# Calulating last Work days on my resignation letter?

Tags: resignation

I had decided to resign from my company on Monday Feb 6, 2017 and according to my contract, its a 60 days notice period. My question is, since February has only 28 days, then what should I enter in my notice letter as my last day?

Edit:
I asked my manager, and he told me its full calendar days and not working days as I recall. But anyways, I speak to him again. I will just enter April 7, and let him know that I cannot stay no later than that date. I am sure he will understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted your HR it's usually their job to calculate this for you?

Comment: Typically this is really defined in terms of  work days,  even if it's often expressed as weeks or months... But, yes, ask HR. You have to tell them anyway...

Comment: I asked my manager, and he told me its full calendar days and not working days as I recall. But anyways, I speak to him again. I will just enter April 7, and let him know that I cannot stay no later than that date. I am sure he will understand.

Comment: This can be answered by getting a calendar and adding 60 days

Comment: related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/does-one-months-notice-period-mean-30-or-31-days/3556#3556

Answer (score 4):

As you've already decided when you're going to resign, just say

> I resign my position at [company name here], effectively immediately as of today, 6th February 2017.

Let HR work out when your final day is.

Answer (score 2):

It's no big deal really. The "60 days" means the company *must* accept a notice of 60 days or more. They *may* accept a shorter notice. So if you gave 59 days because of the February, the can either just accept it, or ask you to change the date.